# What are uses of "Files statically" option inside Package Designer?

Tags: package-designer

Item statically/dynamically is use for creating sitecore item package.

Just for curiosity, want to know about purpose of File statically/dynamically option into Package Designer. In which scenario we can use this option.

[image]

Comment: Files Statically/Dynamically option is used if you want to create a package of physical files i.e. CSS, CSTMLs, JS, Configs. Where as Items Statically/Dynamically 
is used to create a package with Sitecore Content Tree Items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files Statically/Dynamically will be used to package any files under your root website.

When you choose "Files Dynamically", you will be getting various filter options, so if you don't know the source/files and want to search/filter and add them to the package then this will be the better option.

If you know the source of the files before packaging them then "Files Statically" will be the better option. You can simply choose the file root/folder and select the files to the package.

FYI - According to [Sitecore documentations](https://doc.sitecore.com/legacy-docs/SC75/package-designer-admin-guide-a4.pdf)

> You should use static sources when you want to include all the items
>   or files that are stored under a specific node or folder in the
>   content tree or if you only want to include a few specific items or
>   files.
>
> You should use dynamic sources when the items or files that you
>   want to include cannot be easily selected, for example, if you want to
>   include everything created after a certain date.